# Understanding EnvironmentValues syntax

Tags: swift, swiftui

I was spending some time trying to understand the syntax used in `EnvironmentValues` and I was hoping someone could point out if I have made any errors.

```
extension EnvironmentValues {
    var isSensitive: Bool {
        get { self[SensitiveKey.self] }
        set { self[SensitiveKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

My understanding is that the the body of the getter and setter is using *subscript syntax* where the first `self` is referring to the `EnvironmentValues` dictionary as an object. The square brackets allows for a key to be passed into this object. The key itself is a *metatype instance* of `SensitiveKey` which is a previously defined `EnvironmentKey`. It allows access to any type properties and methods, which in this case would be the required `defaultValue` for the `EnvironmentKey`.

Have I understood this correctly? I'd really appreciate if you could clarify any misunderstandings I have here.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You are close. [Per the Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues):

```
private struct SensitiveKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: String = "SensitiveKey" // the default could be anything unique

}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var isSensitive: String {
        get { self[SensitiveKey.self] }
        set { self[SensitiveKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

extension View {
    func isSensitive(_ isSensitive: String) -> some View {
        environment(\.isSensitive, isSensitive)
    }
}
```

The key is just an EnvironmentKey, not a meta type for `isSensitive`. It is literally the key to the dictionary value in EnvironmentValues. `defaultValue` is a poor choice of name that implies mutability as the key itself is immutable.

Also, when you see `.self`, it is the current instance of the type. `.Self` would refer to the type.